# С++ Builder. Форма не видна.

Tags: c++builder

Мне скинули проект на C++ Builder, в котором один умник сделал главную форму невидимой. Я сделал её видимой, однако форма не появляется совершенно при новом запуске.

При этом Builder не зависает, c ним можно делать что угодно. В опциях проекта эта форма - главная.
Вопрос: как заставить заработать программу?

Comment: вариант 1) написать самому.
вариант 2) выложить код, что бы можно было на него посмотреть.

а с "умником" больше дела не иметь или не забыть отдать ему плату:)

Comment: Умника ещё найти надо, тем более по коду - обычная форма, которая, тем не менее, не запускается.

Comment: я думаю, что будет проще, если создадите новый проект, куда аккуратно скопируете содержимое формы и юнита. Подсказка: если перейти на форму и нажать `ctrl+a` `ctrl+c`, то можно "скопировать компоненты", а потом на другой форме с помощью `ctrl+v` вставить.